# deleting only non-existing node which is right next to last node in linked list terminates the program

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

When I delete any node present in a linked list my code works perfectly.
let's say my linked list has 10 nodes, if I want to delete 12th, 13th, 14th... nodes my program gives me the expected message.

But if I want to delete **11th** node(which is adjacent to the last node), my program terminates with exit code `-1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

```
int delete()
{
    int position, count = 1;
    printf( "\nwrite your position" );
    scanf( "%d", &position );

    struct node *p, *q;
    p = head;
    if ( position == 0 ) {
        p = p->next;
        head = p;
        return 0;
    }
    while ( p != NULL && count != position ) {
        count++;
        p = p->next;
    }
    count = 0;
    if ( p == NULL ) {
        printf( "link list is empty or link not found\n" );
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        q = p->next;
        p->next = q->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a sheet of paper and a pencil and consider the situation when the list contains only one node (head)  and the position is set to 1.

Comment: ^^^^ ... or the list is empty (`head == NULL`) and the position is `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i delete qny node present in a linked list my code works perfect

No, it doesn't.  It looks good for deleting the node at index 0, but for any other positive index *n*, it attempts to delete the node at index *n*+1 by advancing pointer `p` to point to node *n* and then manipulating `p->next`.

> but if i want to delete 11th node(which is adjacent to last node) ,my program terminates with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I don't believe that, but I would believe that the program fails when you try to delete the *last* node (rather than one past the last).  In that case, `p` is advanced to point to the last node, whose `next` pointer is null.  Therefore this code:

```
    q=p->next;
    p->next=q->next;
```

sets `q` to a null pointer and then attempts to dereference that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

When `p` is `NULL` then this statement is not valid

```
p->next = q->next;
```

so, the solution is adding `p->next == NULL` statement to `if` condition 
like this:-

```
if ( p == NULL || p->next == NULL ) {
    printf( "link list is empty or link not found\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

now the correct code is

```
int delete()
{
    int position, count = 1;
    printf( "\nwrite your position" );
    scanf( "%d", &position );

    struct node *p, *q;
    p = head;
    if ( position == 0 ) {
        p = p->next;
        head = p;
        return 0;
    }
    while ( p != NULL && count != position ) {
        count++;
        p = p->next;
    }
    count = 0;
    if ( p == NULL || p->next == NULL ) {
        printf( "link list is empty or link not found\n" );
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        q = p->next;
        p->next = q->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this work out when `head` is null on inception (i.e. an empty list on entry)? Ex: suppose `head` is null, and `position` is 0. What happens?